# Access Token error - Graph API getting user profile

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft graph API to get to login and get a users profile. I have the accessToken. Though I'm trying to get the profile of the user that I got the AccessToken with.

This is my code, am I missing anything here? Just need the users profile. Note: I'm using Cors anywhere through a proxy server, which has worked for getting the code and accessToken.

Thanks for your help!

I've tried adding the resource URL. I've tried changing the headers (you don't need body parameters for `GET` and `DEL` requests).

```
let auth =
  "http://localhost:8080/https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?access_token=";
let client_id = "?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
let redirect_uri = "&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8100/";
let response = "&response_type=code";
let resource = "&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com";
let scope =
  "&scope=openid+https://outlook.office.com/Contacts.read+offline_access";

let url =
  auth + token + resource + client_id + redirect_uri;

//let url = 'http://localhost:8080/https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?access_token=' + token +"&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com";
this.http.get(url, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    resource: "https://graph.microsoft.com"
  }
});
```

Expected: to take the AccessToken and get a user's profile like in [Part 4 here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user).

Answer (score 1):

You've got a number of things going on here.

1. You're specifying both `scope` and `resource` properties. These don't belong together. If you're using the v1 Endpoint then you should be using `resource`, if you're using the v2 Endpoint then you should be using `scope`. See [Scopes, Not Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison#scopes-not-resources) in the documentation.
2. Your `url` is not correct. The actual URL should look like this for v1:

   ```
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id={id}&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com&redirect_uri={uri}&response_type=code
   ```

   or for v2, like this:

   ```
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={id}&scope=openid+user.read+contacts.read+offline_access&redirect_uri={uri}&response_type=code
   ```
3. Can't use `http.get()` for this. OAuth's Authorization Code grant starts by *redirecting* the user to this URL. It will then return the `code` you then `POST` back to the `/token` endpoint to retrieve the `access_token` and `refresh_token`.
4. You need the `User.Read` scope to retrieve a user's profile (or `User.ReadBasic.All` to retrieve other user's profiles).

I would recommend using the v2 Endpoint and starting here:

- [Microsoft v2 Endpoint Primer](https://massivescale.com/topic/v2endpoint/)
- [Get access tokens to call Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-overview?toc=./ref/toc.json&view=graph-rest-1.0)
- [AAD v2 Endpoint Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview)

Comment: Great thank you. I'll try those adjustments and revert. Must have been confused.